# extract html table information based on radio button checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, radio-button, selected

Using the example below, what combination of selectors could I use to get the text that contains "price"? (Assume user has clicked a radio button and the Submit button)

```
<table border="1" id="modal_table">
<tbody>
<tr>

<td> <input type="radio" name='sub' value="509"/> </td>
<td> 509 </td>
<td class='price'> Price is $99 </td>

</tr>
<tr>

<td> <input type="radio" value="510"/> </td>
<td> 510 </td>
<td id="price"> Price is $88 </td>

</tr>
</table>

<input type='button' id='idButton2' value="Submit">
```

- get content of td cell that follows the checked radio button, or
- get content of td cell identified by id=price that follows the checked radio button

Answer (score 1):

```
$('tr input[name=sub]:checked').parent().find('#price').html()
```

Answer (score 0):

Great answer!  I had to change `parent()` to `parents()` to get it working. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myButton").click(function () {
            val1 = $("td input[name='sub']:checked").parents().find('.desc').html();
            val2 = $("td input[name='sub']:checked").parents().find('.price').html();
            if (val1 == null){
                alert("Please select one value above");
            } else {
                alert(val1 + " sells for " + val2);
            };
        });
    });
</script>
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>Select</td><td>Product</td>
        <td>Description</td><td>Price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='radio' name='sub' value='ABCDE'></td>
        <td>ABCDE</td>
        <td class='desc'>Product ABCDE</td>
        <td class='price'>55.95</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input type='radio' name='sub' value='GHIFK' ></td>
        <td>GHIFK</td>
        <td class='desc'>Product GHIFK</td>
        <td class='price'>34.99</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input type='button' id='myButton' value="Click Me">
```